# Removing Notepad++ Title Path

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to remove the full file path from the title in Notepad++?

Let's say I only wanted the file name to be displayed there. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Let's say I only wanted the file name to be displayed there. How can this be done?

"Settings" > "Preferences" > "MISC" > "Show only filename in title bar"

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly it :)