# How to show only file names in document switcher in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

The document switcher panel is the one shown in the GIF below:

[image: docswitcher]

I essentially want it to show *file names* instead of *file paths*. Since file paths are of different lengths, it makes it extremely difficult to tell which file I want to go to without having to read the entire line, which is very time consuming.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is here - [Removing Notepad++ Title Path](https://superuser.com/questions/875210/removing-notepad-title-path)

Settings > Misc > Show only filename in title bar

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. I have full paths in the title bar and only filenames in the document switcher.